# Pasting data in between table rows using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert table rows dynamically when clicking an icon next to each table row.  I have the following code that inserts AFTER the whole table :

```
$(document).on('click','.paste_icon',function(){
    var origs=$('.case:checkbox:checked');
    for(var a=0; a<origs.length; a++) {
        addNewRow();
        var arr = origs.closest('tr')[a].id.split('_');
        var id = arr[arr.length-1];
        var dat = getValues(id);
        setValues(i-1, dat);
    }
    $('#check_all').add(origs).prop("checked", false);
    calculateTotal();
});
```

A sample of my table is as such :

```
<input value="<?php echo isset($item['quantity']) ? $item['quantity']: ''; ?>" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_<?php echo $key+1?>" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to insert in between table elements, instead of just at the end?

Requested : (Sample of Table Layout - Very minimal, too much code for full thing)

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<input class="case" type="checkbox"></td> // This adds a checkbox to each row
</td>
<td>
<span class="paste_icon" id="paste_icon_<?php echo $key+1?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-2x"></i></span>
// This adds paste icon to each row
</td>
<td>
<td><input value="<?php echo isset($item['productName']) ? htmlspecialchars($item['productName']) : ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][productName]" id="itemName_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);"></td>
// sample of one item of a few just to show you the $key method of main table
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Add New Row Code For Icon :

```
// Adds row on add icon click
$(document).on('click','.add_icon',function(){
    var add_icon_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var add_icon_arr = add_icon_id.split("_");
    var icon_id = add_icon_arr[add_icon_arr.length-1];
    addNewRow(icon_id);
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Add New Row Function :

```
var addNewRow = function(id){
//table data here
    if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
        $('#tr_'+id).after(html);
    }else{
        $('table').append(html);
    }
    $('#caseNo_'+i).focus();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of your HTML?

Comment: @MdeLorimier what are you looking for?

Comment: I don't see any table elements in your HTML.

Comment: You are talking about a table aind i don't see any in your html. There is also no trace of your #check_all element

Comment: You can insert a row in the middle of the table with `$(selector for row before).after(newrow)`

Comment: @Barmar I am totally new to javascript/jquery - where would I put that in my existing code, and how would I implement it.  Or better yet, do you have a link to documentation & examples?

Comment: You can put an "Add row" button at the end of each row, and then you would use `$(this).closest("tr").after(newrow)`.

Comment: @barmar where in my script would i paste the above line? Sorry, I am TOTALLY new to js/jquery, a friend of mine gave me the code for the addnewrow script

Comment: Sorry, you need to learn to program, you can't just expect everyone else to write it all for you. If you understand how the original code works, it should be obvious how to adapt it to this. Put this code in the `.on("click")` handler for the new buttons.

Comment: @Barmar Not looking for a handout in programming, as stated above, the best answer would include a link to documentation @ examples, thanks for your help, it will be a good starting point

Comment: I posted an answer, but you need to get a jQuery textbook or read online tutorials. I don't think I could find something specific to your question, you need to learn the general principles and then it's merely an application of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button to each row like:

```
<td><button class="addrow">Add row</button></td>
```

and then use the jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".addrow", function() {
    var thisId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
    addNewRow(thisId);
});
```

This gets the ID of the current row. `addNewRow()` takes that as an optional argument, which the above code then passes to it.

Comment: the "<tr> contents of new row would just be replaced with my var origs code above to paste the contents of the checked table elements, correct?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't create the new row, it does something with checkboxes. The code to create the new row is in the function `addNewRow()`, which it calls, but you didn't show the contents of.

Comment: I will post the addnewrow code, which i pretty much understand, the checkbox code copies the checked checkboxes, and returns the tr contents of each checked row

Comment: Sorry, was also adding more relevant code, question updated

Answer (score 0):

I modified code posted by Barmar to make this work, the FULL working code is as follows :

Javascript :

```
    var addNewRow = function(id){

        //Table code here
         if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
                $('#tr_'+id).after(html);
            }else{
                $('table').append(html);
            }
            $('#caseNo_'+i).focus();
            i++;
        }

        // Pastes Row On Icon Click
        $(document).on('click','.paste_icon',function(){
            var origs=$('.case:checkbox:checked');
            for(var a=0; a<origs.length; a++) {

                var paste_icon_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var paste_icon_arr = paste_icon_id.split("_");
                var icon_id = paste_icon_arr[paste_icon_arr.length-1];
                addNewRow(icon_id);
                var arr = origs.closest('tr')[a].id.split('_');
                var id = arr[arr.length-1];
                var dat = getValues(id);
                setValues(i-1, dat);
            }
            $('#check_all').add(origs).prop("checked", false);
            calculateTotal();
        });
var getValues=function(id){
        var inputs=$('#tr_'+id).find('select,input,textarea').filter('[name]');
        var values={};
        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){
            var cur=inputs[i];
            values[cur.name.match(/\[\w+]$/)||cur.name] = $(cur).is(':checkbox, :radio') ? cur.checked : cur.value;
        }
        return values;
    };
    var setValues=function(id,values){
        var inputs=$('#tr_'+id);
        for(var i in values){
            var cur=inputs.find('[name$="'+i+'"]');
            if(cur.is(':checkbox, :radio')) {
                cur.prop('checked', values[i]);
            } else {
                cur.val(values[i]);
            }
        }
    };

//to check all checkboxes
$(document).on('change','#check_all',function(){
    $('input[class=case]:checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Html Table Code Sample :

```
    <table><tr>
<td><input class="case" type="checkbox""/></td><td>
    <span class="paste_icon" id="paste_icon_<?php echo $key+1?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-2x"></i></span>
    </td></tr></table>
```

What this is used for : I have a table that on every table row there is a Checkbox, and a Font Awesome Icon Down arrow.  Using the above code you can click on the Font Awesome Icon to COPY any preselected checkboxed table rows.  Since Barmars suggestions ultimately helped me find the answer, I will select the answer with the most votes as best answer.